# How can I display the contents of a list or a deque in Python?

Tags: python

I have objects which I place on a FIFO implemented as a list and I have a **str** defined for my object. How can I get print(stack) to show the str for the object and not just the reference to the object?

Answer (score -1):

You need to define a `__str__` method for your object.

```
>>> class MyObject:
...     def __str__(self) -> str:
...         return "This is my string!"
...
>>> print(MyObject())
This is my string!
```

Replace with whatever you want the actual string to be!

If you want a string that will be interpolated into *other* objects' `__str__` methods, use `__repr__`, e.g.:

```
>>> class MyObject:
...     def __str__(self) -> str:
...         return "This is my string!"
...     def __repr__(self) -> str:
...         return "REPR"
...
>>> print([MyObject()] * 4)
[REPR, REPR, REPR, REPR]
```

Comment: Actually, you need to define `.__repr__()` to make a list containing your objects look right when printed.  Could simply be `__repr__ = __str__` at the end of the class body.

Comment: ah, I misunderstood and thought their object itself implemented a FIFO

Comment: Thank you, but I still have issues.  What does the -> str mean?  If I print the list which is my stack. it still only shows the object references.  When I did a test print(token) which is a reference to my object I get the usual object reference.  When I copied you print(ClassName()) it assumed that I was making a new object and that the parameters were missing.

Comment: `-> str:` in (modern) Python means "this function returns a string".  If you're using Python 2 just remove the `-> str` part.